# Shiny App Deployment Error building slider (0.2.1)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy a shiny app, however receiving an error:

Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 984403633 failed: Error building image: Error building slider (0.2.1). Build exited with non-zero status: 1

This is not my first shiny app, the previous apps worked fine and are deployed already through this method:

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='jaroslavkotrba', 
                          token='token', 
                          secret='secret')
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp("C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Documents/R/Web_Interactive_Applications_Shiny/Covid")
```

I am using these libraries:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(scales)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
```

R version:

[image]

Comment: It's failing to build the slider package, which must be a dependency of one of the packages you attach. Maybe try to install slider 0.2.2, and load it explicitly.

Comment: I have updated the whole R to 4.1 it is possible to deploy however, the app is not working...

Comment: It's the slider package, not R itself

Comment: I updated the whole R to 4.0 and it works: thanks :) https://jaroslavkotrba.shinyapps.io/covid/ you can place an answer with the update 0.2,2 and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slider 0.2.2 was installed with the new R version.